# can't access the token table yytname in bison 2.6 or is it gone?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm building a parser for an asset xchange format. And I'm including the %token-table directive in the bison file but, from the flex code I just can't access the table or the constants associated with it. That is when trying to compile this code:

```
Frame|FrameTransformMatrix|Mesh|MeshNormals|MeshMaterialList|Material {
    printf("A keyword: %s\n", yytext);
    yylval.charptr_type = yytext;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < YYNTOKENS; i++)
    {
        if (yytname[i] != 0
            && yytname[i][0] == '"'
            && !strncmp(yytname[i] + 1, yytext, strlen(yytext))
            && yytname[i][strlen(yytext) + 1] == '"'
            && yytname[i][strlen(yytext) + 2] == 0)
            return i;
    }
}
```

gcc says both YYNTOKENS and yytname are undeclared. So was the token table finally deprecated and wiped or what's the deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bison 2.6.2 manual says (on p82 in the PDF):

> `%token-table` [Directive]
>
> Generate an array of token names in the parser implementation file. The name of the
>   array is `yytname`; `yytname[i]` is the name of the token whose internal Bison token
>   code number is `i`. The first three elements of yytname correspond to the predefined
>   tokens "`$end`", "`error`", and "`$undefined`"; after these come the symbols defined in
>   the grammar file.
>
> The name in the table includes all the characters needed to represent the token in
>   Bison. For single-character literals and literal strings, this includes the surrounding
>   quoting characters and any escape sequences. For example, the Bison single-character
>   literal `’+’` corresponds to a three-character name, represented in C as `"’+’"`; and
>   the Bison two-character literal string `"\\/"` corresponds to a five-character name,
>   represented in C as `"\"\\\\/\""`.
>
> When you specify %token-table, Bison also generates macro definitions for macros
>   `YYNTOKENS`, `YYNNTS`, and `YYNRULES`, and `YYNSTATES`:
>
> `YYNTOKENS`
>   The highest token number, plus one.
>
> `YYNNTS` The number of nonterminal symbols.
>
> `YYNRULES` The number of grammar rules,
>
> `YYNSTATES`
>   The number of parser states (see Section 5.5 [Parser States], page 104).

It looks like it is supposed to be there.

When I tried a trivial grammar, the table was present:

```
#if YYDEBUG || YYERROR_VERBOSE || YYTOKEN_TABLE
/* YYTNAME[SYMBOL-NUM] -- String name of the symbol SYMBOL-NUM.
   First, the terminals, then, starting at YYNTOKENS, nonterminals.  */
static const char *const yytname[] =
{
  "$end", "error", "$undefined", "ABSINTHE", "NESTLING", "$accept",
  "anything", 0
};
#endif
```

Notes: the table is static; if you are trying to access it from outside the file, that will not work.

There is an earlier stanza in the source:

```
/* Enabling the token table.  */
#ifndef YYTOKEN_TABLE
# define YYTOKEN_TABLE 1
#endif
```

This ensures that the token table is defined.

Comment: So I guess if it's static then my lexer code needs to be inside the generated Bison code?... The docs say you can use Flex with Bison. But the usual way to use it is by having bison generate the header and including that in the flex generator file.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: then, if I have separate flex and bison files and link them via gcc afterwards, I'll need to return a generic keyword token and set yylval in flex code, then create a generic production in bison where if there is a generic keyword I retrieve the yyval to see what's up? Whereas the only way to access the table directly would be if the lexer code was also inside the bison file?

Comment: And yes, btw, you are right.. I was checking the wrong file (a .tab.c from before I switched to %token-table). But still.. I guess I just understood from the docs that the table option was meant to be used with Flex

Comment: The token name table is not usually needed by the Flex lexical analyzer.  You need the `grammar.tab.h` file generated by Bison, or its equivalent.  In general, the token names are not necessarily the same as the spelling of the token in the source code being analyzed.  That is, many grammars use prefixes such as `KW_` in front of the token names, so `KW_SYMBOL` might be the token for `symbol` in the source code the analyzer scans.  The name in `yytnames` would be `KW_SYMBOL'; the lexical analyzer would be looking for `symbol`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quick and easy way around the 'static' issue.  I was trying to print a human readable abstract syntax tree with string representations of each non-terminal for my C to 6502 compiler.  Here's what I did...

In your .y file in the last section, create a non-static variable called token_table

```
%%
#include <stdio.h>

extern char yytext[];
extern int column;
const char ** token_table;
...
```

Now, in the main method that calls yyparse, assign yytname to token_table

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    FILE * myfile;
    yydebug = 1;
    token_table = yytname;
    ...
```

Now, you can access token_table in any compilation unit simply by declaring it as an extern, as in:

```
extern const char ** token_table;

/* Using it later in that same compilation unit */
printf("%s", token_table[DOWHILE - 258 + 3]); /* prints "DOWHILE" */
```

For each node in your AST, if you assign it the yytokentype value found in y.tab.h, you simply subtract 258 and add 3 to index into token_table (yytname).  You have to subtract 258 b/c that is where yytokentype starts enumerating at and you have to add 3 b/c yytname adds the three reserved symbols ("$end", "error", and "$undefined") at the start of the table.

For instance, my generated bison file has:

```
static const char *const yytname[] =
{
    "$end", "error", "$undefined", "DOWHILE", "UAND", "UMULT", "UPLUS",
    "UMINUS", "UBANG", "UTILDE", "ARR", "NOOP", "MEMBER", "POSTINC",
    ...
```

And, the defines header (run bison with the --defines=y.tab.h option):

```
/* Tokens.  */
#ifndef YYTOKENTYPE
# define YYTOKENTYPE
   /* Put the tokens into the symbol table, so that GDB and other debuggers
      know about them.  */
   enum yytokentype {
     DOWHILE = 258,
     UAND = 259,
     UMULT = 260,
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to avoid the static symbol problem is to `#include` the lexer directly in the third section of the bison input file:

```
/* token declarations and such */
%%
/* grammar rules */
%%

#include "lex.yy.c"

int main() {
  /* the main routine that calls yyparse */
}
```

Then you just compile the .tab.c file, and that's all you need.