# token-table; getting information from the table in main.c?

Tags: c, parsing, bison

So, is there a way to extern the token table in my parser.y and get it into my main.c? The reason I ask is because I need my token values to create a structure to save some information about functions in the code it is parsing to see if they are valid or not. I'm looking at this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879140/cant-access-the-token-table-yytname-in-bison-2-6-or-is-it-gone) and I'm not sure how to go about it exactly

Answer (score 1):

I thought all the answers (to the question you cited) covered different aspects of the solutions very well, and all from people who know of what they write. However, I'll try and simplify the explanation for what you are trying to do.

Normally one would build your parser in this way:

```
flex lexer.l
bison parser.y
gcc -o parser.exe parser.tab.c main.c
```

This arrangement is causing issues dues to the scoping of variables in `parser.tab.c` that need to be shared with `main.c`.

Your parser file would normally terminate like this:

```
 #include "lex.yy.c"
```

The simplest solution would be to append `main.c` like this:

```
 #include "lex.yy.c"
 #include "main.c"
```

and now build like this:

```
flex lexer.l
bison parser.y
gcc -o parser.exe parser.tab.c
```

That's about as simple as I can explain it. Hope that helps make it clearer....

Comment: I believe I did something along that line. I'll have to go back and check. But yes, that makes it much more clear than the documentation.